# Trigger comparing two values in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have two items in zabbix, one of tchem is checking certain value for today and other one is looking for same value but from week ago. Can I create trigger which compares them and alerts when one of them is higher than 10% or lower than 15%? I’m running on Zabbix 5.2

Comment: I am looking for the same. Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: You can use calculated items and do all the math that you want